# How does libreoffice express a linebreak when saving a csv?

Tags: linux, mysql, csv, libreoffice, linebreaks

I’m attempting to save a CSV using LibreOffice Calc to be imported to a MySQL database. Saving it as a CSV is pretty straightforward in LibreOffice but I don’t know how the resulting document expresses linebreaks?

My guess is that—since I’m using Ubuntu—it uses the standard Linux notation but I can’t figure out how to confirm that. Whenever I open the CSV in a text editor or use `cat` in the Terminal, it just shows an actual line break.

How can I confirm/check the notation being used?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `file` utility like so: `file <filename>`

For files with *NIX line endings you should see "ASCII text".

For files with Windows line endings you should see "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators".

You can of course use `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` to convert between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **[hex editor](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=hex%20editor)** and open the exported file, and see for yourself.

Comment: If you read the question carefully you'll clearly see that his OS is mentioned.

Comment: You're correct. I updated my answer.